# Prevent the object from moving certain objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I think it is simple, but I don't find the solution. I want my player to move some times red boxes and others blue boxes. I tried to freeze box X position when player collides, but then I have moving platforms so it doesn´t work. I tried to increase the mass, but I have also problems with some situations. Can I know the force that the player is applying in the box in order to apply exactly the inverse force ? Do you think another way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yous shouldn't be freezing the position or changing the mass to get this effect.

If you don't want move any object to be moved by another object, enable `Is Kinematic` on that Object.

`Is Kinematic` description from the [doc](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html):

> If enabled, the object will not be driven by the physics engine, and
>   can only be manipulated by its Transform

```
public Rigidbody redBoxes;
public Rigidbody blueBoxes;
```

Don't move Red and Blue Boxes by another object(Player)

```
redBoxes.isKinematic = true;
blueBoxes.isKinematic = true;
```

Allow movement of Red and Blue Boxes by another object(Player)

```
redBoxes.isKinematic = false;
blueBoxes.isKinematic = false;
```

Comment: In this case, I have to simulate the box gravity by my own, and also if the box is on a moving platform I have to program the movement. I think that freezing the x position and simulating only the last one continue being better. Thank anyway !

Comment: I don't understand your comment about simulating stuff. The question is about prevent object from moving another object.that's what `isKinematic` is used for. You can enable/disable it anytime you want. That's it. There are many issues you will run into when you freeze Rigidbody transform. Although,  I can't stop you from doing that. Do whatever you think works for you.